# Simple code to install a subversion repository on a linux server

Tags: svn, bluehost

What is the simplest way to install a private subversion repository on a Linux server - specifically a bluehost shared server?

Apache version  2.2.13 (Unix)

PHP version 5.2.9

Architecture    x86_64

Operating system    Linux

Commands welcome....

Comment: that it does - thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As wcoenen pointed out, this should be on serverfault.com and the answer I was looking for is the accepted answer at https://serverfault.com/questions/59783/simple-code-to-install-a-subversion-repository-on-a-linux-server/

> I found a great solution at
>   http://www.bluehostforum.com/showthread.php?s=855d68319128c0db09b4d88e844287c0&t=12099&page=3
>   except the most recent version right
>   now is 1.6.5
>
> ```
> mkdir src
> cd src
> wget http://subversion.tigris.org/downloads/subversion-1.6.5.tar.bz2
> wget http://subversion.tigris.org/downloads/subversion-deps-1.6.5.tar.bz2
> tar -xvjpf  subversion-1.6.5.tar.bz2
> tar -xvjpf  subversion-deps-1.6.5.tar.bz2
> cd subversion-1.6.5
> ./configure --prefix=$HOME --without-berkeley-db --with-ssl LDFLAGS="-L/lib64"
> make
> make install
> ```