# Subversion core on a sharedhosting

Tags: svn, bluehost

I've signed up for a shared hosting plan in bluehost and tried installing a subversion by following this instruction: [bluehost forum svn install script](http://www.bluehostforum.com/showpost.php?p=51455&postcount=19) all goes well at first even tried `svnadmin create project_name` and was a success but then when I traverse to `project_name` I got this error "`svn: '.' is not a working copy`" when I run `svn info`.

I think I may have encountered an error on the compilation process, can't remember exactly but i think it has something to do with a ".so" file when I run the `make && make install` command , something about permission.

UPDATE:

Re-run the install again and received this compile error:

```
cp .libs/mod_dav_svn.soT /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_dav_svn.so
cp: cannot create regular file `/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_dav_svn.so': Read-only file system
apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536
.
make: *** [install-mods-shared] Error 1
```

Any help or suggestion is very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally solved it :D I rerun the script with the `–-without-apxs` option

so to modify it from this [find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338484/simple-code-to-install-a-subversion-repository-on-a-linux-server/1391485#1391485), here's the new script:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME –-without-apxs --without-berkeley-db --with-ssl LDFLAGS="-L/lib64" make && makeinstall
```

Comment: for google followers, this is somewhat similar to the apparently lacking "--disable-mod_dav" or "--disable-mod_dav_svn"

Answer (score 1):

when creating files/users or executing commands use su, sudo or the like for your distro to do so ad root.

Edit: Also, most shared host do not allow custom apache extensions.

Try this.

```
cd ~
mkdir src
cd ~/src
wget http://www.gtlib.gatech.edu/pub/apache/apr/apr-util-1.2.12.tar.gz
wget http://www.gtlib.gatech.edu/pub/apache/apr/apr-1.2.12.tar.gz
wget http://subversion.tigris.org/downloads/subversion-1.4.6.tar.gz
wget http://www.webdav.org/neon/neon-0.28.0.tar.gz
tar -xzf apr-util-1.2.12.tar.gz
tar -xzf apr-1.2.12.tar.gz
tar -xzf subversion-1.4.6.tar.gz
tar -xzf neon-0.28.0.tar.gz
cd ~/src/apr-1.2.12
./configure --prefix=$HOME LDFLAGS="-L/lib64"
make
make install
cd ~/src/apr-util-1.2.12
./configure --prefix=$HOME --with-apr=$HOME LDFLAGS="-L/lib64"
make
make install
cd ~/src/neon-0.28.0
./configure --enable-shared --prefix=$HOME LDFLAGS="-L/lib64"
make
make install
cd ~/src/subversion-1.4.6
./configure --prefix=$HOME --without-berkeley-db --with-zlib --with-ssl LDFLAGS="-L/lib64"
make
make install
```

Compliments of [Blue Host Forum](http://www.bluehostforum.com/showthread.php?t=12099)

Comment: I have an ssh access to the account is it still not enough when executing such commands?

Comment: updated the question @Dremation, any ideas? I know its a permission thing but can you explain why? Thanks!

Comment: do you know what flavor of linux you are on? You'll have to try using su or sudo. Ex. sudo make, sudo make install. Check in you /etc/ for the associated release information..Ex 

Novell SUSE /etc/SUSE-release
Red Hat /etc/redhat-release, /etc/redhat_version
Fedora /etc/fedora-release
Slackware /etc/slackware-release, /etc/slackware-version